# Non-mutual exclusivity CASE statements

Tags: sql, case

I have three CASE statements:

```
create view J as 
select *,
  (CASE WHEN A in ('01', ‘03') then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as X,
  (CASE WHEN A = ‘2' then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as Y,
  (CASE WHEN A in ('02', '03') then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as Z
from 
K;
```

I’d like to be able to create one field that contains X, Y, Z as the values. I tried the following but the way in which CASE statements are created forces only the first argument to be true. I understand this is due to the fact that an observation with a value '03' can be in X or Z. Likewise an observation can be in Y or Z.

```
create view J as 
(select *,
(CASE
WHEN X = TRUE then 1
WHEN Y = TRUE then 2
WHEN Z = TRUE then 3
ELSE NULL END)
as grouped_field 
from select 
  (CASE WHEN A in ('01', ‘03') then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as X,
  (CASE WHEN A = ‘2' then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as Y,
  (CASE WHEN A in ('02', '03') then TRUE ELSE FALSE END) as Z

from 
K));
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
concat((case when X = TRUE then '1' else '0' end),
       (case when Y = TRUE then '1' else '0' end),
       (case when Z = TRUE then '1' else '0' end)
      )
```

The concatenation operator differs among databases, but is typically either `||` or `+`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
select *,
  (CASE WHEN A in ('01', '03') then 'X' ELSE '' END) +   
 ','+ (CASE WHEN A = '2' then 'Y' ELSE '' END) +  
 ','+ (CASE WHEN A in ('02', '03') then 'Z' ELSE '' END) as Field
from 
K;
```